# What is the proper way to deserialize an array of of empty objects using jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson's object mapper in java to deserialize some JSON data. I have an object with a field that is sometimes empty, but instead of empty I'm recieving an array of empty objects like below.

```
{
    "LineItems" : [
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

Is there a configuration I can set, is there a deserializer I can use to handle this?

Comment: How about doing some post-processing to remove empty objects after deserialization?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, I just really thought there would be some kind of feature to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon Henrik's answer I ended up doing this:

```
String message = "";//JSON like above
message.replace("{},", "").replace("{}", "").replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
```

Basically replace all instances that have a comma after them, then a single empty value, then empty lines that are left behind. This solution would require some changes if the input isn't formatted the same as mine, i.e. comma's in front of the curly braces, or commas on separate lines.